# Modify part of union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Given an interface like this, is it possible to create a type or code that converts the `null` into `undefined`?

```js
interface A {
  name: string
  foo: string | null
  bar: number | null
}
```

For example, I'd like to turn this into:

```js
interface A {
  name: string
  foo: string | undefined
  bar: number | undefined
}
```

This seemed simple to me at first, but I couldn't find a way to target each props having `type | null` and convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). They distribute over unions, so a type which simply maps `null` to `undefined` while leaving everything else alone will do what you want.

```
type NullToUndefined<T> = T extends null ? undefined : T
type MapNullToUndefined<T> = {[K in keyof T]: NullToUndefined<T[K]>}
```

Example usage:

```
// type Test1 = string | undefined
type Test1 = NullToUndefined<string | null>

// type Test2 = {a: string | undefined, b: number | undefined, c: boolean}
type Test2 = MapNullToUndefined<{a: string | null, b: number | null, c: boolean}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQFQPYFUB2ATCAzAS0wmwB5kA+KAXimSggA9gIcBnKTRBKAfijg58RElABcdALAAoUJCgBZAIZh4SNFlyFiZSjSgBvANoBpKESgBrCCFR46AXQlqUGIdpLlTDigF8ZMgD0gVBy0MgQbMAAjPpRAE5EAOZQAD4C7iLYMmF0kTH6LhqZOqQJyWmc3BQB0sGh4OH5AEz6BkoS5Zgp6YJaWQA0UABGElwAtsMQ8ZV9wjpDAMYSw6ioCBBKmP6yjXlRrbTKqtzF-aXtncCJ3ZVcSEOjVZPTd9xLK2sbW7410kA)

Comment: +1 for a clear and well-written answer, though in my read the OP wanted `NullToUndefined` instead. Easy to extrapolate from your answer all the same.

Comment: Thanks, I was also about to say that. It works after I swapped it. :)

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing that out - a silly mistake!